# Is there a way to trigger notification automatically to match with current date?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to implement birthday notification in my Android app. I have created my own local database where people with their respective birthday is stored. Please help me if there is any way to trigger notification automatically when the `dateofbirth` matches with current date. What I found is all about subscribing by topic or trigger notification based on some event like button click.

Comment: Thanks,in advance!!. It would be helpful if you help me with triggering notification even if the app is not running or is offline.But why i am not getting any help.

Comment: You have a server app? Or just using client (Android) and firebase?

Comment: @Merli_Escarpenter_Perez ,I am  just using client android app.

Comment: Then your unique solution it's create a alarm manager to generate a local notification

Answer (score 3):

You have to implement that logic part for triggering event.

For Example - AlarmManager (in Android)

Or

Use cron job in server.

Comment: Sorry,I didnt get it. Can You elaborate it in detail please.

Comment: Sorry,I have gone through this tutorial http://blog.blundellapps.co.uk/notification-for-a-user-chosen-time/          But while setting reminder using Alarm Manager passing the database values as date of birth  it gives  all the notification at a time(say 45 dateofbirth passed 45 notification at the same time).So it would be efficient if there is a way to do using Firebase Cloud Messaging.

Comment: @Shree, I am not getting what you trying to say.
You can achive things done as below two point.
1> if you want to add this logic in app - use alaram manger 
2> in server- fire cron job at paticular data and time like alaram manger.

the link in your comment matched my first point.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Can you provide your gmail so that i can explain my problem in detail.